# How do I create a docker image from dockerfile and then make a config file available on a volume when running the image from docker-compsose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, config

I am creating a docker container running a python script that collects telemetry. The dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY src/requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY src /app

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

inside the folder 'src' is a folder 'config' with 'config.json' saved 
src/config/config.json

the docker-compose file looks like this

```yaml
version: '2.2'
services:

   umpmfd:
     container_name: mfdwebsockets
     build: mfdwebsockets
     network_mode: "host"
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - "/home/xtp/config.json:/app/config/config.json"   
     depends_on:
       - influxdb
       - grafana
```

I want to have the 'config.json' file available on the host machine so I can change the config with out stopping and restarting the container. At the moment I am getting this error.

> ERROR: for mfdwebsockets  Cannot start service umpmfd: OCI runtime
>   create failed
>   : container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused
>   "process_linux.go:44
>   9: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting
>   \\"/home/xtp/config.jso
>   n\\" to rootfs
>   \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c5a992a5717f2d510e75056ba38ad4075a0
>   31e73ca010fef5da8328ad366eaad/merged\\" at
>   \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c5a992a
>   5717f2d510e75056ba38ad4075a031e73ca010fef5da8328ad366eaad/merged/app/config/conf
>   ig.json\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying
>   to mount
>   a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host
>   path exists
>   and is the expected type
>
> ERROR: for umpmfd  Cannot start service umpmfd: OCI runtime create
>   failed: conta
>   iner_linux.go:346: starting container process caused
>   "process_linux.go:449: cont
>   ainer init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting
>   \\"/home/xtp/config.json\\" t
>   o rootfs
>   \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c5a992a5717f2d510e75056ba38ad4075a031e73ca
>   010fef5da8328ad366eaad/merged\\" at
>   \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c5a992a5717f2d
>   510e75056ba38ad4075a031e73ca010fef5da8328ad366eaad/merged/app/config/config.json
>   \\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to
>   mount a direc
>   tory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path
>   exists and is
>   the expected type

What do I need to change to get this config.json file available as a volume on the host machine?

Comment: Does the file `/home/xtp/config.json` in that exact path exist before you start this?  If not, Docker will create it as a directory and you'll get this error.

Answer (score 1):

> Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?

This is exactly what error message suggests.

Mount directories instead of files.

```yaml
  volumes:
    - "/home/xtp:/app/config"
```